# Magento2 - Sale order grid column "Grand Total (Base)","Grand Total (Purchased)" display default website currency not store or website currency

Tags: magento2, multi-website, currency-rates

I have a multi website store. Each website i have added a base currency and set display currency(both are same). But in the backend sales order grid view for all the orders "Grand total(base)" and "Grand total(purchased)" price currency showing the default website currency not the currency of the website where the order is placed. I have added currency rates for all the currencies in the backend, but no change.

Comment: facing sanme issue